# What could be the reason for a javascript setTimeout taking multiple times as long to execute?

Tags: javascript, settimeout

what could be the reason for a `setTimeout` to wait 2-4 times as long as configured to be executed?

```js
  var TIMEOUT  = 700;

  console.log("TIMEOUT", TIMEOUT);

  var preTimeout = new Date();
  setTimeout(function() {
    console.log("timeout took:", new Date() - preTimeout);
  }, TIMEOUT);
```

This results in `timeout took:` from 1200-4000 on a website.

Comment: this is likely because you have some other script busy doing some work on page..also setTimeout function does is it halt the execution of certain part of code for certain period of time.if you have some other asyc all running in between it might get delayed

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`setTimeout()` doesn't mean execute the code after *exactly* N milliseconds. It rather means, don't execute the code for *at least* N milliseconds.

The asynchronous code such as the `setTimeout()` callback is put on an event loop queue until all syncrhonous code finishes executing, and then it's run. This includes any async code that gets run in the queue before the timeout period. Your callback can run only after all those are done.

Here's a small demo to show this using synchronous `while` loop:

https://jsfiddle.net/foxbunny/1a9rckdq/

Code like the one in the demo is what you'll hear people referring to as 'blocking'. This is because it blocks the event loop queue.

I've also written a somewhat long article on the topic if you want a [throrough overview](https://foxbunny.gitbooks.io/assimilate-js/content/async.html).

Comment: I see, that is what I imagined could be the cause. Can you recommend a way to find out what is causing the long wait? How to profile only or filter the part from timeout queuing to execution?

Comment: I'm not sure if there's a way to see what's in the queue, but profiling tools will tell you what code gets run over the course of the time, so that's probably your first stop. When some code is enqueued, and it gets executed later, it gets executed synchronously, so as long as there's some sync code running, your timeout callback will be delayed. In browsers, this includes rendering code as well.

Comment: Yeah, I spent the last hour (since the creation of this question) in chromes performance tab. Unfortunately, there is so much being loaded/processed that I couldn't find the actual execution of the timeout to go back from there. The profilers search wasn't helpful either. A breakpoint is being ignored when running performance profiling. Do you have any tips?

Comment: Maybe use a named function expression? Like `setTimeout(function OMG_LOOK_AT_ME() { .... }, TIMEOUT);`?

Comment: Btw, "there is so much being loaded/processed" is a problem on its own. :)

Comment: Yeah, it's big third-party software (community board). Not much I can do about that without removing functionality.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/156750/discussion-between-hayavuk-and-user2693017).